# Setting tab index / default button in WinAPI

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a small windows application in which i display a dialog box. In that dialog box i have 2 button "OK" and "Cancel".

**I want to make "OK" button a default button** on that dialog so when enter is pressed we can go straight to processing.

```
IDD_DOMAINVALIDATOR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 247, 180
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_TOPMOST    
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Domain",IDC_STATIC,10,84,44,9
    COMBOBOX        IDNAME,96,79,120,12,CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS
    LTEXT           "Please enter your domain credentials",IDC_STATIC,10,61,230,9
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,96,130,56,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "OK",IDMOK,159,130,56,14
    LTEXT           "Domain username",IDC_STATIC,10,99,58,9
    EDITTEXT        IDUSER,96,95,120,13,ES_AUTOHSCROLL | NOT WS_BORDER,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    LTEXT           "Domain password",IDC_STATIC,10,114,57,9
    EDITTEXT        IDPASS,96,112,120,13,ES_PASSWORD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | NOT WS_BORDER,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
  Reserved",IDC_STATIC,10,171,228,9
    CONTROL         IDB_BANNER,IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_BITMAP,0,0,248,52
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do this by setting one of the buttons to have the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style.